# How open link copied from clipboard in separate tab?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a task: clicking on the item the link copied to the clipboard, after clicking, this link should be opened in separate Tab (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). I use Action but it not help

```html
FluentWebElement urlButton = within(secs(5)).button(By.className("btn btn-link table-text table-text ft-link"));
        urlButton.click();// after clicking, link copied to clipboard
        
        // trying open new tab
        delegate.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+ "t");
        
        // trying past link
        Actions actions = new Actions(delegate);
        actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "v")).build().perform(); 
        pauseFor(5000);
```

I'll be grateful for the advice. Thank you!

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I don't get any error, but the new tab and URL doesn't open, just nothing happens.

Comment: Does the entire link gets copied to the clipboard? Or only the additional part e.g. `/dashboard` gets copied to the clipboard? Update the question with the _String_ which gets copied to the clipboard, the initial _url_ and the resultant _url_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved using the system Clipboard:

```html
        FluentWebElement urlButton = within(secs(5)).button(By.className("btn btn-link table-text table-text ft-link"));
        urlButton.click(); //copied to clipboard
        
        
        //get copied string from clipboard
                    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
            String paste = (String) clipboard.getContents(null).getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            
            //open in separate tab
             JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) delegate;
            js.executeScript("popup_window = window.open('"+ paste+ "');");
            pauseFor(3000);
            js.executeScript("popup_window.close()");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascripts executor after click event

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
 js.executeScript("window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');");
```

Comment: how to past the copied URL using Ctrl+V?

Comment: You can pass your url into this code window.open('url','_blank'); as variable

Comment: I don't know the URL which copied to a clipboard. After each click on the item, the URL is always different, so I need use ctrl+V

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on link a new Tab is opening, so you need to **switch** the focus of your **WebDriver**, in order to perform anything on the newly opened tab.

```
 public static void main(String args0){

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

  //Some operations on Page 1  (Page 1 is cuurent Page that you are working).
 //Click on link on Page 1.

  ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
  driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

  // performs some operations on Page 2
    Actions actions = new Actions(delegate);
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "v")).build().perform(); 
    pauseFor(5000);

   driver.close();
   driver.switchTo.windows(tabs.get(0));
}
```